# Regression and percentile

Tags: probability, regression

> On a midterm exam, the average is $50$ points (out of $100$) with an SD of $10$ points.  On the final exam, the average was $100$ points (out of $200$) with an SD of 30 points.  The correlation between the two is 0.6.
>
> What percent of the people who got a 40 on the midterm improved their percentile on the final?

The solution given in this case is 31% but it doesn't seem right to me .

I started the question by first standardize the score of 40 on midterm:

$\frac{40-50}{10}=-1$

Thus the same percentile of score on final would be $-1*30+100=70$

I then solve for the new average for the final score of the people who got 40 in the midterm, I get: $-1*0.6*30+100=82$

Finally I solve for the z score of the people who were 1 standard deviation below the new average and use normal approximation to get the percentage of people who improved on their final grade:

$\frac{70-82}{\sqrt{1-0.6^2}*30} = -0.5$

-0.5 corresponds to 30.85% under the curve, we are interested in people who improved in their final score therefore we get: 100%-30.85%=69.15%

Is my solution correct in this case??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will solve this according to the least-squares regression line equation.

The linear relation between $2$ variables $x$ & $y$ is given by the equation for the regression line,$$ Y= \beta_o+\beta_1Χ+e.....(1)$$

Where $Y$ is the dependent variable

$Χ$ is the independent variabl

$\beta_o$ is the y-intercept.It is the value of Υ for Χ=0

$\beta_1$ is the slope of the line.It gives the amount of change in $Y$ for every unit change in $Χ$.

$e$ is the random error.

The predicted value of $Y$ for a given value of $Χ$ is denoted by $Y^{\prime}$

$$Y^{\prime}=a+bx.....(2)$$where $a= \beta_0^{\prime}=$ the estimated $y$-intercept of the regression line

and $b=\beta_1^{\prime}=$ the estimated slope of the regression line.

Regression line of $y$ on $x$ is $y-\overline{y}=byx(x-\overline{x}).....\overline{y}$ is the mean of $y,\overline{x}$ is the mean of $x.....(3)$

we consider $x$ is the midterm exam score

$y$ is the final exam score

Given midterm mean $=50=\overline{x},\overline{y}=100$

and the standard deviation for $x=10$ and $y=30$ $$byx=r\times\dfrac{\sigma}{\sigma x}=0.6\times\dfrac{30}{10}=1.8$$
Plug in these values in $(3)$, we get
$$y-50=1.8(x-50)$$
$$y=1.8x+10$$$\beta_0$ is the $y$-intercept $=10$

$\beta_1$ is the slope of the line $=1.8$

Now, plug these in $(1)$, we get

If $X=40$ then 
$Y^{\prime}(40)=82$

Therefore, the predicted final exam score is $82$

Comment: should not the adjusted SD for $y$ be $30\cdot \frac{100}{200}=15$?

Comment: @farruhota I didn't get where you pointed the mistake, but thanks, I corrected few things where I took wrong mean and SD of final.

Comment: in that case, note $0.6\cdot \frac{30}{10}=1.8$ and $y=1.8x+10$, so $y(40)=82$ just like the OP found.

Comment: @farruhota Thanks, for correcting me.

Comment: you are welcome. Originally, when you used $\bar{x}=50, \bar{y}=50$, I thought you were converting to percentage mark (adjusting to 100), nevermind.

Comment: @KeyFlex I get the predicted final score part but what about the question "What percent of the people who got a 40 on the midterm improved their percentile on the final?" the solution I got is 69% whereas the solution shows 31 %

Comment: @KeyFlex thank you for confirming that

Comment: @pino231 $31$ % under the curve resembles the percentage of students who improved their score in the final

Comment: @KeyFlex why would it be 31% and not 69%? The average final score of people who got 40 on the midterm is 82 and if they had scored the same percentile as their midterm the final score would have been 70, then shouldn't it be 69% of them all improved?